# How to document use of Rails' url_helpers using YARD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, yard

When trying to generate YARD documentation for a service implemented with Rails, I get the following warning:

```
$ yardoc
[warn]: in YARD::Handlers::Ruby::MixinHandler: Undocumentable mixin: 
          YARD::Parser::UndocumentableError for class MyClass
[warn]:     in file 'app/models/my_class.rb':7:
  7: include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

My understanding is that YARD cannot determine the mixin's type, since that's only available at runtime.

So what's the right thing to do here? Is it possible to correctly document the mixin? If not, how do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1542

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to correctly document the mixin?

Apparently not, The mixin's methods (URL helpers) remain undocumented by YARD unless manually documented elsewhere in your project's documentation.

[John Bachir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168143/john-bachir) mentions [`lsegal/yard` issue 1542](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1542), which is more about helping to manage warnings and keep the CI pipeline clean: it does not provide a direct path to documenting the methods brought into the class by the `url_helpers` mixin within the YARD documentation itself.

A Rails-specific solution involves wrapping the `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` statement inside an [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), which can bypass top-level inclusion warnings by YARD's parser.

```rb
module WithRoutes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
  include WithRoutes
end
```

Or you can create a YARD extension that overrides the warning behavior for specific patterns, allowing you to bypass warnings for `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`:

```rb
# yard_extensions/ignore_rails_mixin.rb
module IgnoreRailsMixin
  def process
    super
  rescue YARD::Parser::UndocumentableError => e
    raise e unless statement.last.source.start_with?("Rails.")
  end
end

YARD::Handlers::Ruby::MixinHandler.prepend(IgnoreRailsMixin)
```

Then, use this extension when running YARD:

```bash
yard doc -e yard_extensions/ignore_rails_mixin.rb --fail-on-warning
```

The alternative would be to implement a [CI script to filter out "undocumentable" warnings](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1542#issuecomment-2016695382) while failing on other types of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

[Yard Undocumentable Error docs](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/YARD/Parser/UndocumentableError) The description might answer your question. To get rid of the warning, as per my knowledge, running `yardoc` in quiet mode is the option:

```
yardoc -q /path/to/source/file
```